# why wordpress form not passing values to the result page

Tags: php, wordpress

when i submit my form the values are not passing to the action url instead it shows the result in search page .my form action url is mysitename/showresults when i submit the form in the url it shows as mysitename/showresults but the value in that template is not echoing instead it shows the results from search.php file. Thanks in advance this my form
;   This area onlyWithin ¼ mile     age 3 4 5

Comment: some code of my form
<form method="post" action="sitename/showresults">; <input name="location" type="text" > <select id="radius" name="radius" class="short"> <option value="0.0" selected="selected">This area only</option><option value="0.25">Within ¼ mile</option><option </select> <select name="curriculum" class="select"> <option value="" name="curriculum"></option> </select> <select name="age" class="drop-b"> <option value="">age</option> <option value="3">3</option> <option value="4">4</option> <option value="5">5</option> </select> <input title="" name="submit" type="submit" />

Comment: Make sure "showresults" isn't some kind of reserved string, or an actual alias to Wordpress' search. For a sanity check, you could try naming the results page to something other than "showresults".